# How to generate an installer with Installshield from any branch

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installshield-2013

I have a branch schema with a structure like this:

- Develop

  - Branch 1
  - Branch 2        .         .           .

I have successful created my installer project from Develop branch, but I can´t generate the installer from other branchs (like Branch 1 or Branch 2).

To generate an installer from other branchs I need to remove and add again the Project Output.

My objective is generate a branch from Develop and be able to generate the installer from this branch, without change anything. Is it possible?

EDITED:

Files that are inside the project I can insert it with with relative path. But primary output that point for projects (dll or executables) I can´t insert relative path.

[image]
The problem is when I make a branch from develop (that have everything configured) the paths for the dll or executable, primary output still point to Develop branch, witch make the installer do not work.

Comment: If you switch from [TFVC to Git](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/code/overview) inside TFS it makes stuff like this a lot easier because branches are still represented by the same path. However it is not a simple task to convert from TFVC mode to Git mode, some information like changeset history could get lost.

Comment: None sense.  Source code should always use relative path reference or other abstractions so that absolute paths are not required.  This is for workspaces from one developer to another developers machine, one build box to another or one branch to another.  There's nothing fundamentally wrong with TFVC that a switch to Git would solve the problem.

Comment: Where does he say he uses TFS anyways?

Comment: I am using TFS. But change for Git is impracticable.

Comment: I'm also facing same type of issue. If I'm taking an installer project from another machine to my machine then it's difficult to change all relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Your installer should live in the same branch and use relative path references so that this isn't a problem.  Otherwise you can use InstallShield Path Variables to bridge the gap.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I have edited my question and included more information. I can use relative path for files inside the project (and it works fine), but when the primary output is a dll or executable I can´t insert relative path. In fact the path even appears, what make me believe that it should works in any branch. But when I check for path it still point to Develop Branch.

Comment: Personally I don't recommend using project references or keeping the InstallShield code and the Application code in the same solution.  What I like to do is have application in one solution and use postbuild events to stage a model of the deployed application in a directory underneath the installer solution that InstallShield can access with a relative path.  Then I explicitly author my components based on what files I want to deploy.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, do you have some example? I have no idea how to make an installshield project in a diferente solution!!